# How to turn a long mongodb aggregation into easily readable code

Tags: mongodb, coding-style, domain-driven-design, backend, api-design

I have recently had to replace my nice and neat functional approach to database reads for a complex route with a long aggregation because it was a lot more performant and was wondering what approaches people take to splitting up long aggregations into something readable. I really want a better solution that just slapping comments on each stage of the pipeline to walk other developers through it

I am not able to change the function of or post the aggregation. I am purely interested in how to make long aggregations more readable. Readings and research resources are appreciated

Comment: What about using `$function`? You can still use JS code inside the `aggregate`? But, you might face the performance issue. Or you could use `variables` outside the `aggregate()` and then use place this to each stage of your code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code better readable you can for example write it like this

```
var match = {inserted: ISODate("2021-07-01T00:00:00Z")};
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match: match} 
])
```